# phpMyDataGrid select field， dynamiclly make dropdown list menu from other tables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datagridview, datagrid

I am using phpMyDataGrid , and I cannot make the dropdown list menu in a column.

```
$objGrid = new datagrid; 
$objGrid->closeTags(true);   
$objGrid->friendlyHTML();   
$objGrid->methodForm("get");  
$objGrid->conectadb("localhost", "root", "", "STEM_DB");
$objGrid->salt("Myc0defor5tr0ng3r-Pro3EctiOn"); 
$objGrid->language("en");
$objGrid->buttons(true,true,true,false);
$objGrid->Form('grant', true);
$objGrid->searchby("GrantName");
$objGrid->tabla ("GrantProgram");
$objGrid->keyfield("GrantID");
$objGrid->datarows(20);
$objGrid->orderby("GrantName", "ASC");
$objGrid->FormatColumn("GrantID", "Grant ID", 5, 5, 0, "5", "center", "integer");
$objGrid->FormatColumn("GrantName", "Grant Name", 20, 20, 0, "100", "center", "text");
$objGrid->FormatColumn("Funder", "Funder", 20, 20, 0, "100", "center", "text");
```

This line doesn't work:

```
$objGrid->FormatColumn("Personnel", "Personnel", 100, 100, 0, "100", "center","SELECT 
* FROM Personnel");
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/stem/phpmydatagrid.class.php on line 1079

line from 1077 to 1085 are following

```
                        case 'select':
                            $strInput.= "<select id='$fldname' class='dgSelectpage' >$br";
                            foreach ($selData as $key=>$value){
                                $selected=($value==$default)?"selected='selected'":"";
                                $strInput.= "<option value='$key' $selected. >$value</option>$br";
                            }
                            $strInput.= "</select>";    
                            $campos[] = $fldname;
                        break;
```

And the FormatColumn() function is like this:

```
# FormatColumn: Define fields to show and their settings
function FormatColumn($strfieldName, $strHeader, $fieldWidth=0, $maxlength=0, $inputtype=0, $columnwidth=0, $align= 'center', $Mask='text', $default='', $cutChar=0){
    if ( $strfieldName=="" or !$this->validField( $strfieldName)){
        $mask = strtolower($Mask);
        $this->fieldsArray["$strfieldName"]["strfieldName"] = $strfieldName;          # Field Name
        $this->fieldsArray["$strfieldName"]["strHeader"]    = $strHeader;             # Title to show in top of grid
        $this->fieldsArray["$strfieldName"]["fieldWidth"]   = $fieldWidth;            # Input size
        $this->fieldsArray["$strfieldName"]["maxlength"]    = $maxlength;             # Input maxlength
        $this->fieldsArray["$strfieldName"]["columnwidth"]  = intval($columnwidth)."px"; # Column width
        $this->fieldsArray["$strfieldName"]["align"]        = $align;                 # Left, center, right, justify
        $this->fieldsArray["$strfieldName"]["mask"]         = $Mask;                  # Mask for data output
        $this->fieldsArray["$strfieldName"]["default"]      = $default;               # Default value for new records
        $this->fieldsArray["$strfieldName"]["select"]       = '';                     # Auxiliar field for data in masks (check, select)

        $this->fieldsArray["$strfieldName"]["cutChar"]      = $cutChar;               # Amount of chars to show.

        $datatype='text';
        if ($mask=='textarea') $datatype='textarea';
        if (substr($mask,0,5)=='image') $datatype='image';
        if (substr($mask,0,9)=='imagelink'){ $datatype='imagelink'; }
        $pmask = !(strpos($this->numerics,trim($mask)) === false);
        if (substr($mask,0,5)=='money' or $pmask)$datatype='number';
        if (substr($mask,0,4)=='date') $datatype='date';
        if (substr($mask,0,4)=='link') $datatype='link';
        if (substr($mask,0,4)=='calc') {$datatype='calc'; $this->hasCalcs = "true"; echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var thereisCalc = true;</script>";  $inputtype=3; }
        if (substr($mask,0,5)=='chart'){$datatype='chart'; $this->hasChart = true; $inputtype=5; 
            if (strpos($mask,':') > 0) {
                $arrMask=explode(':',$Mask); $arrMask=array_slice($arrMask,1);
            }else{ 
                $arrMask=array("none:sum");
            }
            $this->fieldsArray["$strfieldName"]["select"] = $arrMask;
        }       
        if (substr($mask,0,4)=='bool' or substr($mask,0,5)=='check'){ $datatype='check';
            if (strpos($mask,':') > 0) {
                $arrMask=explode(':',$Mask); $arrMask=array_slice($arrMask,1);
            }else{ 
                $arrMask=array($this->message['false'],$this->message['true']);
            }
            $this->fieldsArray["$strfieldName"]["select"] = $arrMask;
        }       
        if (substr($mask,0,6)=='select'){ $datatype='select';
            $maskData = array();
            if (strpos($mask,':') >0 ){
                $mask=explode(':',$Mask);
                if (strtoupper(substr($mask[1],0,7)) == 'SELECT ') {                    #Select data from Table. Format [SELECT key, value FROM table]
                    if ($this->isADO){
                        if (($objResult = $this->connectionHandler->Execute($mask[1])) === false)
                                $this->SQLerror($mask[1],$this->connectionHandler->ErrorMsg());
                        while (!$objResult->EOF){
                            $arrResult = $objResult->fields; 
                            $maskData[$arrResult[0]]=$arrResult[1];
                            $objResult->MoveNext();
                        }
                    }else{
                        $objResult = mysql_query($mask[1]) or $this->SQLerror($mask[1], mysql_error());
                        while ($arrResult = mysql_fetch_array($objResult))
                            $maskData[$arrResult[0]]=$arrResult[1];
                    }
                }else{                                                                  #literal select: keyfield must be of the same datatype as the list
                    $arrMask=array_slice($mask,1);
                    foreach ($arrMask as $ArrData)  {
                        $arrOptions = explode( '_', $ArrData);
                        $rowID = $arrOptions[0];
                        if (isset($arrOptions[1])) $rowName = $arrOptions[1]; else $rowName = $rowID;
                        $maskData[$rowID]=$rowName;
                    }
                }
                $this->fieldsArray["$strfieldName"]["select"] = $maskData;
            }
        }
```

Anybody can help? Thanks in advance

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"? Any error or something?

Comment: Yes it is error:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/stem/phpmydatagrid.class.php on line 1079

Comment: I'm assuming that line you provided is line 1079?

Comment: No Adi, I just update the question, and providing the error codes

Answer (score 1):

On *phpmydatagrid*, when using a query as data input mask, the statement shall follow the pattern bellow:

```
SELECT key, value FROM table
```

Besides that, the parameter shall have the "select:" prefix.
As an example, your statement should read:

```
$objGrid->FormatColumn("Personnel", "Personnel", 100, 100, 0, "100", "center","select:SELECT idPersonnel, name FROM Personnel");
```